# Odoo 12 : how to add domain depending on related field?

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

I have two `many2many` related field, let's call them `field_one` and `field_two` and one `many2many`, let's call it `field_three`.

Here are the definition of the three fields :

```py
field_one = fields.Many2many(comodel_name="res.partner", related="project_id.field_one")
field_two = fields.Many2many(comodel_name="res.partner", related="project_id.field_two")
field_three = fields.Many2many(comodel_name="res.partner", relation="acco", column1="ac", column2="co")
```

When the user want to add partner(s) (`res.partner`) in the `field_three`, those partner(s) that already in `field_one` and `field_two` should not be in scrooling list in the `field_three`.

How to i proceed to do that? Thank you very much.<

I used `api.onchange("field_one", "field_two")` but it doesn't work.

PS : We are in `"project.task"` model here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use XML domain:

For old version of Odoo (I think < 11) there was a solution for this :

```xml
  <field name="field_three"
    ....
    ....
    domain = [('id', 'not in' , field_one[0][2])]/>
```

This solution doesn't work but after some debuging I found out that Odoo 
store the selected Ids in the `_store` attribute. If you want to exclude selected
partner from the search list use this domain.

```
       domain = [('id', 'not in' , field_one._store), ('id', 'not in', field_two._store)]
```

This worked for me just fine in Odoo 11 hope it work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Please make the field_one and field_two store.

```
field_one = fields.Many2many(comodel_name="res.partner", related="project_id.field_one", store=True)
field_two = fields.Many2many(comodel_name="res.partner", related="project_id.field_two", store=True)
```

Comment: Thank you very much @AnithaDasB. I will test your solution and I will upvote it if it works

Comment: Doesn't work. What I want is to add domain when form view is loaded, i tried with the built in method "fields_view_get" bit doesnt work.